# HowTo: Custom Field in Lift-Record-Squeryl

Tags: scala, lift, record, squeryl

I'm trying to make a `EnumListField` in Lift/Record/Squeryl, similar to `MappedEnumList` in `LiftMapper`. The storage type should be Long/BIGINT. I understand that if I define:

```
def classOfPersistentField = classOf[Long]
```

Then Squeryl will know it should create a BIGINT column. And I know it uses `setFromAny()` to set the value, passing in the Long. The one piece I don't get is:

How will it read the field's value? If it uses `valueBox`, it will get a `Seq[Enum#Value]`, and it won't know how to turn that into a Long.

How do I tell Squeryl to convert my `Seq[Enum#Value]` to a Long, or define a "getter" that returns a Long, and that doesn't conflict with the "normal" getter(s)?

Comment: This link might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175645/squeryl-custom-field-types

Comment: its not possible, you have to try it other way of series which are just like similier to your requirement. for this you can try MSDN help.

Answer (score 1):

you are implementing your validation logic incorrectly. The correct way to validate a Record field is to override

```
def validations: List[ValidationFunction]
```

where ValidationFunction is a type alias

```
type ValidationFunction = ValueType => List[FieldError]
```

and in your case ValueType == String.

The next issue is your Domain trait. Because your call to validate is inlined into the class definition, it will be called when your field is constructed.

Comment: I haven't used Scala, and therefore Lift/Record/Squeryl, for over 5 years. I've forgoten all about it, and so I'm not qualified anymore to decide if your answer is correct and solves the problem. I'm not sure what the Stack-Overflow "process" should be in this case. I'll ask in "meta" ...

Comment: "Meta" said "wait and see"; if your answer gets a bunch of +1, then it's "probably right", and I can accept it...